# repeating data, how to parse for easy access?

Tags: python, dictionary, struct

I receive a large amount of data, hundreds to thousands of lines. The format is the same, about 50 lines of data, then the same type of data repeats. I know what the data represents but the data received does not contain this.

So the data received will look like:

```
     Value(int):       703                                                    
     Value(int):       12                                                     
     Value(int):       58                                                     
     Value(int):       0                                                      
     Value(int):       -1                                                     
     Value(int):       88                                                     
  Value(string):       272                                                    
  Value(string):       01                                                     
     Value(int):       61                                                     
     Value(int):       0                                                      
     Value(int):       0
```

But I know what each thing means, eg:

```
fcn:Integer
Range: 0 to 16383
Code:Integer
Range: 0 to 511
CountryCode:String
^\d{3}$
NetworkCode:String
```

So these repeat, what would be an easy way to parse this data so that I could look at say the first element of each repeating series and so on to compare them? Can I make a struct? Do I need a dictionary, or how do I do this? I'm not sure if these kind of questions are allowed, basically want to know how you would do it and why.

Here is one round of the repeating data, I have stuck in what each name is for each of the values. So where I would just be receiving `Value(int):     1` I know that it is the `Band Name`:

```
Band Name: 
     Value(int):     1
Cell Scan Time
  Value(string):     2013-04-03T08:21:10Z
       Sequence: 
       Sequence: 
ARFCN/UARFCN --->2112.8 MHz DL / 1922.8 MHz UL
     Value(int):       10564
RSSI
     Value(int):       39
BSIC/SCODE
     Value(int):       263
RXQUAL
     Value(int):       0
FREQ OFFSET
     Value(int):       9
FREQ QUAL
     Value(int):       90
MCC
  Value(string):       272
MNC
  Value(string):       05
LAC
     Value(int):       67
RAC
     Value(int):       67
RNC Identity
     Value(int):       708
Cell ID
     Value(int):       130
CPICH TX POWER
     Value(int):       31
Patch Loss
     Value(int):       102
CPICH EC over N0
     Value(int):       -5
CPICH RSCP
     Value(int):       -76
RXLEV + CPICH EC
     Value(int):       0
TX Diversity

QQUAL MIN
     Value(int):       -20
QRXLEV MIN
     Value(int):       -111
HCS Priority
     Value(int):       -1
DeltaQHcsRscp
     Value(int):       -1
Scan Temperature 
     Value(int):       0
```

The following is only repeated once every few sets of data received with the rest being repeated in the same format always:

```
Band Name: 
     Value(int):     1
Cell Scan Time
  Value(string):     2013-04-03T08:21:10Z
       Sequence: 
       Sequence:
```

Complete output sample: http://pastebin.com/ArGfm2cD

EDIT:

I have my data stored in a variable currently:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_rancli, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc_stdout  = proc.communicate(ran_opt_get_access_data)[0]
print proc_stdout
```

Comment: Call Detail Records? I'd stick them in a database, because I can separate the collection from the processing and form complex queries based on the dataset. Typed columns and indexes would allow me to quickly extract useful information based on need.

Comment: Part of being a programmer is assessing what it is you are trying to achieve, what the constraints are and which tools you should use. If the tools you're familiar with are suitable for the task then you have a look for some which are more suitable. Failing that you write your own.

Comment: Indeed, I am trying to do that. I know how to do it in a way that I view is bad (new to python), so am looking for more tools to use that I have not used before, whether it be a named tuple or a struct or so on.Interested in seeing how other people would do it and if it would vary.

Comment: Your question is overly broad right now and risks being closed. I suggest you supply two or three records and the field definitions and limit your question to how to parse the data, not what to do with it afterwards.

Comment: added, including a  full output sample of the data received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to better understand the problem: How do you synchronize with your data stream?
What I got is that you get this values one after each other and you have to place them in a structure implemented someway.
This needs to be performed differently if you have a continuous stream or a text file.
Anyway, assuming that you get a stream and you know that the first value is X, the second Y and so on you can:

1) create a dictionary or a class with all the fields needed.

2) take the fields you receive and check the type ( if you expect an int you can check if "int" is in the string you receive for example)

3) make the conversion and manage possible exeptions (if you find "int" but then you find "gatto" there is an error

4) put the value that you extract (if the line is "Value(int): 10" you can just do `int(line.split(":")[1]))` in the correct position in your data structure
and so on.

If you receive a sequence you should also check type consistency in the sense "if in the third position I wait a string what happens if I get an int?"

Is it clear or you need more explanations/examples?

Comment: I am sorry I did not say how I have my data. I have it all stored in a  variable, I will add it to the bottom of my question and read through your answer

Comment: So I have the variable, it has all the sets of repeating data, do I first have to parse these out into different variables containing each set (somehow, now and again there is the extra few lines of data received as shown in the question)? Then add each set to a different dictionary with differing names? Or the dictionary would be overwriting the values I put in?

Comment: @Paul: Looking at your pastebin, the data isn't particularly well-formatted for machine reading. I see that you're using the output of some form of CLI. Perhaps whatever it is you're using has a machine-readable output or interface?

Comment: The output does indeed come from a cli. However this is the only way I can get the data. Here is a more accurate pastebin, it's better formatted: http://pastebin.com/2FFNa3Qx

Comment: Perhaps I could split the data at "sequence:" into different lists, and then split them with \n and see if there is 22 elements in each list, then use the data. As each repeat I want to look at should have 22 elements.

Comment: @Paul You can use different dictionaries or the same, it depends if you want to keep the values in the ram or not.
Now, normally if you write 2 values at the same address you overwrite the first (ex: `dic[a] = 1` and then `dic[a]=2` at the end you have 2 in dic[a]). Even if the data are not very well formatted for machine reading they are not so critical to be read so don;t worry. What I suggest you is to prepare a list of possible items that can appear in the file and try to recognize them separately.
If then there are common parts go for regular expressions. You have 2 linked problems here.

Comment: thanks, I would like to keep the data as it has to be compared. The first element of the one dictionary vs the first element of the second dictionary and the first element of the third etc. All the elements seem to be too similar to recognize them separately. I think maybe a list of lists.